# Keras Conv2D layer has different output when using AWS Sagemaker

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker

I've been trying to train a model on AWS Sagemaker as I found that my computer is no longer powerful enough to train my model in a reasonable amount of time. However, when I tried to load the model (after copy pasting the code from my computer) I got an unexpected error.

After tinkering around for a little bit, I found that the very first Conv2D layer has a different output shape than it was on my computer.

Sagemaker output dimensions:

`(None, 128, 498, 3)`

Expected output dimensions:

`(None, 498, 498, 3)`

My code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.Input(shape = (500,500,3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What error did you receive? Did you confirm you are using the same TensorFlow version that was on your local machine?

Answer (score 2):

I came here, because I had the same problem. I found the solution, but I am still really confused about it. I just want to mention that I use the same tensorflow version locally and on sagemaker (2.10). And on both EXACTLY the same code.

If you go https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/
It states:

"Output shape

4+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (filters, new_rows, new_cols) **if data_format='channels_first'** or 4+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (new_rows, new_cols, filters) **if data_format='channels_last'**. rows and cols values might have changed due to padding."

So I forced the Sagemaker's version to *`data_format='channels_last'*
Now both version the local one and AWS one are consistent.

`

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras import backend
backend.set_image_data_format('channels_last') #channels_first for NCHW
```

this could solve your problem because tensorflow on sagemaker expect by default the channel first